# mythtv backend package build options

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv

I would like to know if the MythUbuntu mythtv backend 0.25 (12.04) was built with `--enable-libx264` or `--enable-libmp3lame` options.

These options are needed to use the torc ios app and probably also with the new VDR xbmc 12.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the 0.25 builds are built with both --enable-libx264 and --enable-libmp3lame (I've included the configure line below). You can see one of the build logs at https://launchpadlibrarian.net/127352145/buildlog_ubuntu-quantal-amd64.mythtv_2%3A0.25.3%2Bfixes.20130102.ff8c496-0ubuntu0mythbuntu4_BUILDING.txt.gz

```
cd mythtv && ./configure --compile-type=profile --prefix=/usr --runprefix=/usr --enable-crystalhd --enable-lirc --enable-audio-alsa --enable-audio-oss --enable-dvb --enable-ivtv --enable-firewire --enable-joystick-menu --with-bindings=perl --enable-ffmpeg-pthreads --enable-pic --enable-vaapi --perl-config-opts="INSTALLDIRS=vendor" --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libfaac --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-opengl-video --enable-vdpau
```